# Login the site using Facebook option is not working in my PHP sites

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-login

I 've created  "login using facebook" sections in [http://domain.com](http://domain.com/mysite/) and [http://domain.com/mysite](http://domain.com/mysite/) sites. These sections were working fine till few weeks before. But from yesterday when I try to login using facebook to one of these sites, it shows an error

> "An error occurred with your website. Please try again later."

and directly redirect to facebook account only. I also tried a demo link in  tutorial site http://onlinewebapplication.com/facebook/
. it also shows the same error.  I want to know that the problem is in coding part in the website or facebook changed anything in their system. Sorry for my bad english. Does anyone know a solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint www.facebook.com/login.php has been deprecated and taken out of action recently.

You’ll have to rebuild your login procedure to comply with the techniques described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/

If you are using the PHP SDK to create the login URL – make sure you’re using the latest version.

Comment: Thanks bro.I'll check with latest version of PHP SDK